# Send Ctrl + d to a server via bash

Tags: bash, rhel6

I'm working on a script, that requires you press `control + d` when you complete your entries.  I'd like to send this command so I can just script my work rather than having to redo my work.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: Ctl-d is just how you send EOF from an interactive terminal. If you're piping input to a program, it will get EOF at the end of the pipe, you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably talking about the "end of transmission" delimiter which is used to indicate the end of user input. If that's the case then you can always pipe data into your script. That is, instead of this:

```
$ test_script.sh
My input!
^D
```

You'd write that data to a file:

```
$ cat > input
My input!
^D
```

Then pipe that into the script:

```
$ test_script.sh < input
```

No `^D` is required because once that file is fully read the script is signalled accordingly. The `<` shell operator switches STDIN to read from a file instead of the terminal. Likewise, `>` can be used to capture the output of a program and save it to a file, as done in the second step here, though you can use any tool you'd like to create or edit that input file.

This works with pretty much any scripting language, from Python, Perl, Ruby to Node.js as well as bash and other shells.